# How to filter all the event handler in c# word addin (consists of Winforms) like e.g. java servlet filter

Tags: c#, winforms, vsto, word-addins

I am developing a word addin which contains a ribbon tab, few custom taskpanes and some winforms.

I need to **filter all the click event (all events including wordapp event handler, control click event, ribbon button click event etc.)**,
before it goes to event handler associated with that corresponding control.
I need to check some properties before any event handler gets fired just like we do in java servlet filter for every request.

Is it possible to define filter like some class that gets called before any event handler? If possible How can I implement it?
I would appreciate any help. Thanks